# Setting displays force close error in texter application

Tags: android

How can I set the settings configurations for android application for a text er application. When I run the application, and click on menu in emulator, in the bottom of the screen I get settings tab. When I select that settings tab, I get force close error. What is the problem behind this error.

I have added the logcat errors in this link

http://pastebin.com/QrY3L1DY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.texter.QUICKTEXT }

Have you set up the activity in your manifest file correctly??

Something like this:

```
<activity android:name="quicktext"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.texter.QUICKTEXT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have made the changes you have given me. But still problem isnt solved. Any other options can u guide me. Thanks a lot for taking time in replying me sir. Please guide in me in solving this issue.

Comment: Are you using preference activity for your settings?

Comment: I wrote this small tutorial on preference activity, take a look. It may help. Example project included.